wxWidgets internal image function can't load large PNGs?
I have a (unusual big) PNG with an image size of 29000x29000 pixels where the wxWidgets-internal image handlers fail to load it.
What I can see:
In file src\png\png.c function png_check_IHDR() there are several checks agains the size of the image such as
if (width > PNG_UINT_31_MAX)
...
if (height > PNG_UINT_31_MAX)
...

where PNG_UINT_31_MAX is 2147483647 and therefore much bigger than my 29000 and such as
if (width > png_ptr->user_width_max)
...
if (height > png_ptr->user_height_max)
...

where user_width_max/user_height_max are 1000000 and therefore also much bigger than my 29000 pixels.
But later function wxImage::Create() fails to allocate the required memory, the call to
M_IMGDATA->m_data = (unsigned char *) malloc( width*height*3 );

does not come back with allocated memory. So despite the previous size-checks the image size seems to be too big.
As other picture viewers/editors load this image properly: is there a solution available for this problem? May be in any newer version of wxWidgets (I'm running v 3.1.4 but can't update it easily just for a simple test...)?
Thanks!
Update: it is the call to malloc( width * height * 3 ). Normally, 29000 * 29000 * 3 would be 2523000000, but when jumping into malloc(), than handed over size is MUCH bigger. So my current solution is to do some casts here:
malloc( ((size_t)width)*((size_t)height)*((size_t)3) )

Anyway, is this a knwon wxWidgets/Windows/VisualStudio problem?

you can try to compile 3.2 and see if it works by trying image sample.

@Igor let me quote from my original question: "I'm running v 3.1.4 but can't update it easily just for a simple test"

I'm not asking for an update. I'm asking if you can build 3.2 independently and test the image sample. Just download it and unpack in the new directory. or even use different machine. You already have the image in question - why not try it.

@Igor OK, I meanwhile found the sources in GIT, there it seems to be fixed. But the same problem exists in https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/src/common/image.cpp#L235 - the clear-function does not make use of a proper cast and will cause a crash with the current implementation. It better should be something like memset(M_IMGDATA->m_data, value, ((size_t)M_IMGDATA->m_width)((size_t)M_IMGDATA->m_height)((size_t)3));

please post on the wx-dev ML or open an issue on GitHub.... when opening an issue -attach the image you use. Also I'm not sure I understand - you said that it is fixed but then say that the issue is still exist. Which one is it?

It seems that the limitation is still present in 3.2.x versions, see comment and check in wxImage::Create, so you'll still have problems loading 29,000 × 29,000 images since 2,523,000,000 exceeds MAX_INT (2,147,483,647).

Allocating memory for such an image requires about ~2.5GiB, so it's quite possible (and all but guaranteed if you use 32-bit OS) that memory allocation may fail in this case.
If you do have enough memory and use 64-bit build, it should succeed, but it's probably still a bad idea to load such image entirely into memory. I don't know what do you plan to do with it, but there are almost certainly better ways of doing it.

Please refer to the discussion above: the problems are caused by a wrong calculation of the size to be malloc()ed in wxImage::Create() (which is fixed in latest sources but still exists in exactly the same way for the memset()-size used in wxImage::Clear())
